# Java getBytes UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java

I am trying to deal with an encoding problem (I want to transform the special characters from a string into correct UTF-8 characters...):

When I execute this simple code:

```
System.out.println(new String("&eacute;".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

In the console I expect: 'é' but I get

```
&eacute;
```

Comment: What? How do you think those characters should produce `é`?

Comment: Are you thinking of HTML encoding?

Comment: The `String` instance creation expression you've used is effectively a no-op.

Comment: First you get bytes from a Unicode string `&eacute;` and then you convert it back to `String` in `UTF-8` encoding... no wonder you get the output you get.

Comment: For the moment I am thinking "printing 'é' in the console". But yes, program injects this String in a mongodb collection for html display.

Comment: Also note the [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) feature in later Java versions. Especially good [if you don't like catching exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) that should never occur anyway.

Comment: @Tyvain,  maybe you should change the title of this question, since it's nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding, and it's actually about unescaping an HTML entity reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&eacute;` is the HTML entity reference for the `é` character, not the UTF-8 encoded string. To decode it, you can use Commons Lang's [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html):

```
String decodedStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&eacute;");
```

Comment: Perfect! PS: took commons-lang3-3.3.2 and used unescapeHtml4

Answer (score 1):

Java Strings know nothing of SGML / XML / HTML5 entities. `&eacute;` is such an entity. It works in web browsers inside HTML because in one of the DTDs, or the HTML5 spec, it's defined that `&eacute` is the letter e with accent acute by mapping it to the corresponding unicode character entity `&#xe9;`.

`new String(someString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");` is a meaningless operation, it converts a String into bytes, with an encoding that can represent all meaningful characters, and converts it back into a String. It's the same thing as using `someString` directly, just you have a new object.

In order to get e with accent acute, you can do one of the following things:

- Directly type it, like `System.out.println("é");`. This requires that your text editor and your Java compiler agree on the encoding of the source code file. If you're working in a project, it requires that everybody understands and agrees on a particular encoding. Recommended encoding these days certainly is UTF-8.
- Use the Unicode character number. In the case of e acute it would be `\u00e9`.

P.S.: SGML / XML / HTML5 entities have nothing to do with UTF-8.

Comment: I find this "new String(someString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");" in many answers refering to the same problem... For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253322/getbytes-with-utf-8-doesnt-work-for-upper-case-german-umlauts

Comment: @Tyvain That was just to show how to correctly encode and decode using the same character set. It isn't meant to be a piece of code that should be used in production software.